# Showing a specific web page when client connects directly to an access point from a web browser

Tags: linux, routing, wireless-access-point

I have Linux (Debian) machine as my Wi-Fi access point (AP). It’s an AP and it provides DHCP and DNS, too.

With my client machine I am connecting to this AP.

Now I want to achieve this behavior: When on client machine I open `nameofap.local` in web browser website from AP (`192.168.1.1`) should be shown.

I tried to modify `/etc/hosts` on AP but it does not work.

I don’t want to edit something on client machine, I want to do it on AP, so any client connects to AP and open `nameofap.local` in web browser, website from AP is presented.

How to do it please?

Comment: Is the Linux AP also a router, or just a bridge? Does it provide DHCP and/or DNS services?

Comment: yes, AP is also router, it provides DHCP and DNS, too.

Comment: So if someone accesses this access point directly via a web browser, you want the access point to serve a web page, correct?

Answer (score -1):

Your clients cannot automatically know the router's `/etc/hosts` content – it has to be provided using DNS.

This means that you need to advertise the router's own address<sup>1</sup> as the *only* DNS server, and that DNS server software must actually support loading custom records from `/etc/hosts`.

(For example, Dnsmasq will read `/etc/hosts` entries automatically. Unbound doesn’t support that but you can use `local-data:` settings instead.)

---

<sup>1</sup> Doesn't have to be the router itself, but it does have to be a DNS server that you control, and you cannot mix it with other servers that don't know about your custom additions.

Comment: Did you read the question? The original poster wants people who connect to the access point via a web browser to be served a specific page.

Comment: You mean the sentence "any client connects to AP and open nameofap.local in web browser"?